# How can we auto generate additional testing users with custom password for new DX Scratch Orgs?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm looking to setup a custom config for DX Scratch orgs. And would like to generate at least 2 additional test users in the new scratch org being created.

Can anyone suggest a way to do that?

Comment: Scratch orgs only come with two full Salesforce licenses. What license or access level do you require?

Comment: A non admin - Salesforce Platform licence is actually needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can script user creation with Salesforce DX. The [`force:user`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_user.htm#!) command tree has what you need:

`force:user:create` creates a user, given a [user definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_users_def_file.htm#!). It takes optional flags `generatepassword=true` and `permsets=<Name>` to configure the user immediately. The user definition file lets you set the profile and other user attributes.

`force:user:display` gives you back information about the user (use the `--json` flag to get the details in machine-parseable format). It includes the user password.

`force:user:password:generate` lets you generate a password for any user that didn't have it set upon creation.

Comment: is it possible to set the password to a user-defined value while generating the user or change password later via command line?

Comment: I've never tried to do so. I don't see a way to do that in the SFDX command set.

Comment: You can't do that directly with sfdx, but you can do that with an anonymous apex script that you invoke from sfdx.   The apex method to reference is System.setPassword(userid, password).